# Navigating to users profile using React mentions

Tags: reactjs, mention

I used React mentions component in my project to pop up list of user suggestions when I type @ in the input of the comment section, but after posting the comment I don’t know how I’m suppose to get the id of the mentioned user so as to be able to navigate to the profile of the mentioned user when I click on the mentioned name.

I need a situation where by when I post the comment an array of mentioned users is created and I can navigate to the individual profile of the users that were mentioned

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.